# C# Code to Change Between Any Two Number Bases

Tags: c#

I'm working on a problem from exercism.io that asks for a function s.t. given an array of digits, a specified input base (e.g. base 2) and an output base (e.g. base 10), the output of the function will be an array of the digits of that same number in the new base.

E.g. if the input is `Rebase(2, { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 }, 10)` the output should be `{4, 2}`

I have tried to implement a solution to this problem that first rebases the number to base 10, and then rebases the number according to the method on [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_logical_organization/number_system_conversion.htm) where you take the remainder and quotient of division by the base to find the digits of the number.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class AllYourBase
{
    public static int[] Rebase(int inputBase, int[] inputDigits, int outputBase)
    {
       int baseTen = 0;
       int remainder;
       int quotient;

       LinkedList<int> coeffHolder = new LinkedList<int>();
       if (outputBase <= 1)
        throw new ArgumentException();


    if(inputBase <= 1)
        throw new ArgumentException();


    for(int i = inputDigits.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        baseTen += (int)inputDigits[i] * (int)Math.Pow(inputBase, i);
    }

    quotient = baseTen;


    while(quotient > 0)
    {
        remainder = quotient % outputBase;
        coeffHolder.AddFirst(remainder);
        quotient = (int)quotient / (int)outputBase;


    }

    return coeffHolder.ToArray();
    }

}
```

As described above my expected output for `Rebase(2, { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 }, 10)` is `{4, 2}`, but for some reason the answer I'm getting is `{2, 1}`.

I'm not certain why I'm getting a result that is half what I'm expecting.

P.S. I know there's in-built ways to change the base, but as this is an exercise I'm inclined much more to convert it via my own function implementation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and look for where a variable diverges from what you'd expect.

Comment: @itsme86 this is probably the best advice.  I'm not very adept at using a debugger, so these small errors always trip me up.

Comment: Visual Studio has an excellent debugger. I highly recommend familiarizing yourself with it. It'll save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: @Mascasc At some point you need to learn the debugger and the one in VS is very good. You might as well start using it now, while you have simple problems to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're processing the digits in the reverse order (right to left) and decreasing the exponent of 2 (input base) as you go (from right to left).

This processes digits left to right with decreasing power of 2 (inputBase).

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputDigits.Length; i++)
{
    int j = inputDigits.Length - (i + 1);
    baseTen += (int)inputDigits[i] * (int)Math.Pow(inputBase, j);
}
```

Comment: Wow, you're exactly right.  This explains why the converter was working for single digit numbers, there was no possibility for this mis-indexed array to cause a problem in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In your conversion loop here:

```
for(int i = inputDigits.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    baseTen += (int)inputDigits[i] * (int)Math.Pow(inputBase, i);
}
```

You're saying that the right most digit is two raised to the power of five (most significant digit), when it should be two raised to the power of zero (least significant digit).

Change:

```
    baseTen += (int)inputDigits[i] * (int)Math.Pow(inputBase, i);
```

To:

```
    baseTen += (int)inputDigits[i] * (int)Math.Pow(inputBase, (inputDigits.Length-1) - i);
```